# Attempt to de-reference a null object - Trigger to auto add products based on value in selected product

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, opportunity-lineitem

I'm working on a trigger for OpportunityLineItems that looks at the value for "add_for__c" for the product selected and if it is 0, it needs to find all other products in the same pricebook that has an "add_for__c" value that matches the value in the initial product's "lsrv_pk__c" field and then insert the initial product and those matching products.

I've found two other sources who were attempting to do something similar and have been working with their existing code, but when I test I'm getting the error mentioned above. It is referencing line 41 which is:

```
    if(itemProductA.lsrv_pk__c == pbeProduct2.add_for__c){
```

I thought maybe I needed to add a list for pbeProduct2, but that didn't fix it.  Other than improving how get values from my first item, I'm stuck for what to do about my error.

Any suggestions?

Here is my trigger:

```
trigger Product_Auto_Add on OpportunityLineItem (before insert) {

List<OpportunityLineItem> oliList = new List<OpportunityLineItem>(); 

List<String> lstProduct = new List<String>();

for(OpportunityLineItem optLineItem: Trigger.new)
{
    if(optLineItem.add_for__c == '0')
    {
        lstProduct.add(optLineItem.lsrv_pk__c);
    }
}

//retrieve values of Product Selected
List<OpportunityLineItem> lstOpptyLineItems = [SELECT OpportunityId, Name, PricebookEntryId, Quantity, add_for__c, lsrv_pk__c, UnitPrice
                                               FROM    OpportunityLineItem
                                               WHERE   Id = :Trigger.new 
                                               AND lsrv_pk__c IN:lstProduct];

//create a map which contains Product lsrv_pk and OpportunityLineItem
Map<String, OpportunityLineItem> mapOpptyLineItem = new Map<String, OpportunityLineItem>();
for(OpportunityLineItem item:lstOpptyLineItems)
{
    mapOpptyLineItem.put(item.lsrv_pk__c, item);
}


//retrieve PriceBookEntry of the Product B, this is most important
PricebookEntry pbeProduct2 = [SELECT Id, Pricebook2Id, UnitPrice, Name, add_for__c
                              FROM PricebookEntry 
                              WHERE Pricebook2Id IN 
                              (SELECT Id FROM PriceBook2 
                               WHERE Name = 'Selectcom Telecom Pricing') 
                              LIMIT 1];


//retrieve Product A item from the map.         
OpportunityLineItem itemProductA = mapOpptyLineItem.get('Product A');

if(itemProductA.lsrv_pk__c == pbeProduct2.add_for__c){
    
    
    oliList.add(new OpportunityLineItem(
        OpportunityId = itemProductA.OpportunityId, 
        PricebookEntryId = pbeProduct2.Id,
        Quantity = itemProductA.Quantity,
        UnitPrice = pbeProduct2.UnitPrice)
               );
    
    insert oliList;
}
```

}

Comment: In `before insert` trigger the records have no id, so the query with `WHERE Id = :Trigger.new` will return an empty list, therefore the map will be empty and `mapOpptyLineItem.get('Product A');` will return `null`. That's why `itemProductA.lsrv_pk__c` throws a NPE.

Comment: Should I change it to after insert instead? Would that work?

Comment: It will not throw an exception, but that code isn't bulkified: you only create just one OpportunityLineItem. Moreover why you query and retrieve several OLI when you only use a single one, the one with `lsrv_pk__c  ==  'Product A'` (the one you get from the map)? Finally what if two or more OLI have the same `lsrv_pk__c`? You'll use only the last one due to `Map.put()` behavior.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not understanding.  I'm still learning, but I am using the `lsrv_pk__c == pbeProduct2.add_for__c` aren't i? `if(itemProductA.lsrv_pk__c == pbeProduct2.add_for__c){` I understand your second comment as that will be a scenario where there will be 2 or more with `lsrv_pk__c == 0`, so I would need to loop through all those selected correct?

Comment: You put N OLI in the map with `lsrv_pk__c` as key, then you get the one with key `'Product A'`, so `itemProductA` is the OLI with `lsrv_pk__c == 'Product A'`, therefore the if-block `if(itemProductA.lsrv_pk__c == pbeProduct2.add_for__c)` will be executed only if `pbeProduct2.add_for__c` is `'Product A'`. 1) What should happen to the records with `lsrv_pk__c != 'Product A'`? 2) You could use `lstProduct` in the WHERE condition of the query on PricebookEntry.

Comment: About the second part, since you could have two or more records with the same value of `lsrv_pk__c` (i.e. N records with `lsrv_pk__c == 'Product A'`), you should change your `Map<String, OpportunityLineItem>` to a `Map<String, List<OpportunityLineItem>>` in order to handle them.

Comment: If `lsrv_pk__c != pbeproduct2.add_for__c` I don't want that product.  I only want those where `lsrv_pk__c = pbeproduct2.add_for__c`.  Do I still need to add 1stProduct to my WHERE condition in that case?  Regarding your last comment, let me clarify that the values of lsrv_pk__c are unique. It's just that in order to build logic to bundle them we have the add_for__c field which, when it is a secondary product, will have a matching value to the lsrv_pk__c field of its primary product. So now I'm just really confused! haha